# jQuery each() to loop through list items and do something for each item separately

Tags: jquery, each

I have a list of Events in my calendar (generated by the CMS) and some of these events have a "Coming Soon" status instead of online registration link. I was to change the Coming Soon text to a mailto link and grab the event title and append it to the mailto Url, something like mailto:info@domain.com?Subject="event-title-here".  This way the recipient will know which event is the email regarding to.

This is my HTML:

```
<ul class="events">          
    <li>
        <div class="day-month">
            <span class="day">12</span>
            <span class="month">Dec</span>
        </div>
        <div class="info">
            <a class="event-title" data-sf-field="Title" data-sf-ftype="ShortText" href="#">Event Title 1</a>
            <span class="city-state"><i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i>Foster City, CA</span>
            <span class="registration"><a href="#">Register Now</a></span>
        </div>              
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="day-month">
            <span class="day">12</span>
            <span class="month">Dec</span>
        </div>
        <div class="info">
            <a class="event-title" data-sf-field="Title" data-sf-ftype="ShortText" href="#">Event Title 2</a>
            <span class="city-state"><i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i>Foster City, CA</span>
            <span class="registration"><span>Coming Soon</span></span>
        </div>              
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="day-month">
            <span class="day">12</span>
            <span class="month">Dec</span>
        </div>
        <div class="info">
            <a class="event-title" data-sf-field="Title" data-sf-ftype="ShortText" href="#">Event Title 3</a>
            <span class="city-state"><i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i>Foster City, CA</span>
            <span class="registration"><a href="#">Register Now</a></span>
        </div>              
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="day-month">
            <span class="day">12</span>
            <span class="month">Dec</span>
        </div>
        <div class="info">
            <a class="event-title" data-sf-field="Title" data-sf-ftype="ShortText" href="#">Event Title 4</a>
            <span class="city-state"><i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i>Foster City, CA</span>
            <span class="registration"><span>Coming Soon</span></span>
        </div>              
    </li>
</ul>
```

I added a class to the span that wraps around the Coming Soon text and I thought this is how I can loop through those events:

```
(function ($) {
    $('.registration span:contains("Coming Soon")').addClass('email-updates');

    $('.email-updates').each(function() {
        var eventTitles = $(this).closest('.event-title').text();
        $('.registration span:contains("Coming Soon")').html('<a href="mailto:info@domain.com?Subject=' + eventTitles + '>Sign up for email updates</a>');
    });

}(jQuery));
```

but this didn't work for me. How do I get **Event Title 2** and **Event Title 4** in this example and append them to their links after **?Subject=** in each mailto href?

Comment: Are you able to add "email-updates" class to the "span". I mean, when you inspect element, can you see that "email-updates" class to the span?

Comment: Yes, I can see <span class="email-updates"> in the code. The CMS does not generate the second span (the one inside span class="registration") instead, it created the registration Url with a

Comment: let me if the answer works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use the below code:

```
(function ($) {
 $(document).find('.registration span:contains("Coming Soon")').addClass('email-updates');
  setTimeout(function(){
      $(document).find('.email-updates').each(function() {
          var eventTitles = $(this).closest('.event-title').text();
          $(this).html('<a href="mailto:info@domain.com?Subject=' + eventTitles + '">Sign up for email updates</a>');//You missed the closing double quotes here 
       });
  },500);

}(jQuery));
```

When we add dynamically elements or class to the DOM, then we can't access them. We need to access them through $(document).

Comment: This kinda works, I think the only piece that is not working is "var eventTitle = $(this).closest('.event-title').text();" because nothing is being attached to ?Subject=. I also tried putting eventTitle on console but the titles are not showing in console either. Thanks

Comment: @Marz please check the updated answer. You missed the closing double quotes in href

Comment: I did and still not working for me "$(this).html('<a href="mailto:info@domain.com?Subject=' + eventTitles + '">Sign up for email updates</a>');"

Comment: Strange, this is working at my end. Is there any error in your console?